# gam plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I need to create some gam plots in ggplot. I can do them with the general plot function, but am unsure how to do with ggplot.  Here is my code and plots with the regular plot function. I'm using the College data set from the ISLR package.

```
train.2 <- sample(dim(College)[1],2*dim(College)[1]/3)
train.college <- College[train.2,]
test.college <- College[-train.2,]
gam.college <- gam(Outstate~Private+s(Room.Board)+s(Personal)+s(PhD)+s(perc.alumni)+s(Expend)+s(Grad.Rate), data=train.college)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(gam.college, se=TRUE,col="blue")
```

Comment: See help("plot.gam") and look under *Value* there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## See update below old answer.

### Old answer:

There is an implementation of GAM plotting using ggplot2 in `voxel` library. Here is how you would go about it:

```
library(ISLR)
library(mgcv)
library(voxel)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
data(College)

set.seed(1)
train.2 <- sample(dim(College)[1],2*dim(College)[1]/3)
train.college <- College[train.2,]
test.college <- College[-train.2,]
gam.college <- gam(Outstate~Private+s(Room.Board)+s(Personal)+s(PhD)+s(perc.alumni)+s(Expend)+s(Grad.Rate), data=train.college)

vars <- c("Room.Board", "Personal", "PhD", "perc.alumni","Expend", "Grad.Rate")

map(vars, function(x){
  p <- plotGAM(gam.college, smooth.cov = x) #plot customization goes here
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
}) %>%
  {grid.arrange(grobs = (.), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)}
```

after a bunch of errors: `In plotGAM(gam.college, smooth.cov = x) :
  There are one or more factors in the model fit, please consider plotting by group since plot might be unprecise`

[image]

To compare to the `plot.gam`:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(gam.college, se=TRUE,col="blue")
```

[image]

You might also want to plot the observed values:

```
map(vars, function(x){
  p <- plotGAM(gam.college, smooth.cov = x) +
    geom_point(data = train.college, aes_string(y = "Outstate", x = x ), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_rug(data = train.college, aes_string(y = "Outstate", x = x ), alpha = 0.2)
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
}) %>%
  {grid.arrange(grobs = (.), ncol = 3, nrow = 2)}
```

[image]

or per group (especially important if you used the by argument (interaction in gam).

```
map(vars, function(x){
  p <- plotGAM(gam.college, smooth.cov = x, groupCovs = "Private") +
    geom_point(data = train.college, aes_string(y = "Outstate", x = x, color= "Private"), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_rug(data = train.college, aes_string(y = "Outstate", x = x, color= "Private"  ), alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_color_manual("Private", values = c("#868686FF", "#0073C2FF")) +
    theme(legend.position="none")
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
}) %>%
  {grid.arrange(grobs = (.), ncol = 3, nrow = 2)}
```

[image]

### Update, 08. Jan. 2020.

I currently think the package [mgcViz](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcViz/) offers superior functionality compared to  the `voxel::plotGAM`function. An example using the above data set and models:

```
library(mgcViz)
viz <- getViz(gam.college)
print(plot(viz, allTerms = T), pages = 1)
```

[image]

plot customization is similar go `ggplot2` syntax:

```
trt <- plot(viz, allTerms = T) +
  l_points() +
  l_fitLine(linetype = 1)  +
  l_ciLine(linetype = 3) +
  l_ciBar() +
  l_rug() +
  theme_grey() 

print(trt, pages = 1)
```

[image]

This [vignette](https://mfasiolo.github.io/mgcViz/articles/mgcviz.html) shows many more examples.

Comment: I'm getting this error after running that code.  Error in plotGAM(gam.college, smooth.cov = x) : gamFit is not a object of type gam

Comment: What library is the `gam` method you are using? If you could swap to `library(mgcv)` and `mgcv::gam` it would probably work.

Comment: @missuse, is it possible to plot two different models on the same plot, one for each level of 'Private', instead of using the interaction?

Comment: @fibar Yes. generate two models, then generate two plots and then combine in one plot using `gridExtra`, `cowplot` or any of the other few packages ment for this sort of thing.

Comment: @misuse I noticed that `plotGAM` and `plot` have different y axis. The y axis in `plotGAM` is predicted value of dependent variable. What does the y axis in `plot` mean? Their values are not the same (e.g., _8000~16000_ V.S. _-6000~6000_ ).

Comment: @T X good catch. Here is an answer addressing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764810/changing-the-y-axis-of-default-plot-gam-graphs. When I get some time to research I will edit the answer.

Comment: Interestingly the gam model fitted now is different then the one fitted when the answer was posted using the same code.

Comment: great answer! love the series with the blue dots!